# how to append multiple query parameters in url - NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, e-commerce, vue-router, nuxt.js

I am creating a nuxt ecommerce application. I have a situation where I have more than 10,000 items in a category and i want to create related filters for the products.
My question is how do i append url (add & remove query parameters) so that i can filter products.
I have tried something like this by adding a `change` event to !

```
      <ul>
        <li>
          <b-form-checkbox @change="filterProduct">
            <label class="ui__label_checkbox">Apple</label>
          </b-form-checkbox>
        </li>
         <li >
          <b-form-checkbox @change="filterProduct">
            <label class="ui__label_checkbox">Mango</label>
          </b-form-checkbox>
        </li>
      </ul>

methods:{
  filterProduct() {
      this.$router.push({ query: Object.assign({}, this.$route.query, { random: "query" }) });

    },
}
```

This approach **does** append the url only once but removes the checked state of the checkbox which i don't want

I want similar to below everytime i click checkbox, it must retain the state of the checkbox at the same time append to the url

```
www.foobar.com/?first=1&second=12&third=5
```

Comment: Why do you need them as route parameters? Could you not set an item in your vuex state that contains the parameters and apply them on the page you navigate to?

Comment: @Andrew1325 do you think 10,000 items would fit in vuex state ???

Comment: Are you putting 10,000 items in your route parameters??? I understood you want parameters that you use to filter your 10,000 items. Set the filters and use them in mounted() or asyncData on your 'navigated to' page.

Comment: @Andrew1325 you dont want to directly query 10,000 items all at once in the application. Having said that, my question was simple in the context of a typical ecommerce site. the results are probably limit to sequential sets to lower the load on server.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you should do. First of all, you should all your filters state in `data()`

```
data() {
    return {
        filter: {
            first: this.$route.query.first || null,
            second: this.$route.query.second || null,
            third: this.$route.query.third || null
        }
    }
}
```

Then you set up a watcher that fires when any filter changes, obviusly you need to v-model the inputs in your `<template>` to the fields in `data()`

```
watch() {
    filter: {
        handler(newFilters) {
            const q = complexToQueryString({
                ...this.filter,
            })

            const path = `${this.$route.path}?${q}`
            this.$router.push(path)
        }
    }
}
```

The complexToQueryString function is a thing of mine which removes null values from the query and also works for filters that are arrays. I did this because my API reads null as String 'null'.

```
const complexToQueryString = (object, parentNode = null) => {
    const query = Object.entries(object).map((item) => {
        const key = parentNode ? `${parentNode}[${item[0]}]` : item[0]
        const value = item[1]

        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            return arrayToQueryString(value, key)
        } else if (value instanceof Object) {
            return complexToQueryString(value, key)
        } else if (item[1] !== undefined) {
            return [
                Array.isArray(item[0]) ? `${key}[]` : key,
                encodeURIComponent(item[1]),
            ].join('=')
        }

        return ''
    })
        .filter(empty => empty)
        .join('&')

    return query
}
```

Now it should work, if you change the filter value then the data.filter.first changes the value, which fires the watcher, which updates the URL.

The best thing about this aproach is that now you can copy & paste the URL and the filter is exactly the same and returns the same result.

Comment: Don't you have to use `this.$route.query.first` istead of  `this.$route.params.first` ?

Comment: It is Working with this answer

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is almost correct, except that on page request, router-level You should append all the query parameters to route params.

Then asign those params to data inside Your filter page, and mutate them, also updating the query like You're doing now. This way You'll have query updated, and checkboxes wont lose state as they will depend on data, rather than on params.

```
routes: [{
        path: '/path',
        component: Component,
        props: (route) => ({
            filter1: route.query.filter1,
            filter2: route.query.filter2,
            filter3: route.query.filter3
        })
    }]
```

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, does nuxt even have `routes` property per page? I am using nuxt for ssr featured application.